# How do I set flycheck-markdown-mdl-rules

Tags: customize, flycheck, markdown

I'm trying to get FlyCheck to ignore a rule used by mdl for checking syntax for.md files.  I'm not very lisp or emacs savvy, but I've added this code to my personal.el file.

```
;; Turn off mdl message [MD013] Line length
(defcustom flycheck-markdown-mdl-rules '("~MD013")
  "Ignore line length."
  :group flycheck-markdown-mdl-rules
  :type '(string)
  )
```

I don't get any compilation errors, but mdl doesn't ignore the "line length" check like I'd expect.  Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have another option to get the same effect. You can create a `.mdlrc` file with the following content. This should allow you to ignore the "line length" check.

```
verbose true
rules "~MD013"
```

You will find more information here: [Mdl configuration](https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint/blob/master/docs/configuration.md)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I actually tried that route originally.  Unfortunately, the snap installation of mdl doesn't play well with .mdlrc files.  See my post here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/604564/114944